# Match all URLs in string and return in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

For example, I have the following string:

```
var string = 'watch this video http://vimeo.com/8122132 and then see this picture http://www.flickr.com/photos/pmorgan/32606683/';
```

I wish to find all the valid URLs and place them in an array, done in JavaScript (and jQuery), so in this case:

```
url[0] = http://vimeo.com/8122132
url[1] = http://www.flickr.com/photos/pmorgan/32606683/
```

For now, I can only match one URL, but I wish to match all. This is what I have:

```
geturl = new RegExp("(^|[ \t\r\n])((ftp|http|https|gopher|mailto|news|nntp|telnet|wais|file|prospero|aim|webcal):(([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*(),;/?:@&~=-])|%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){2,}(#([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*(),;/?:@&~=%-]*))?([A-Za-z0-9$_+!*();/?:~-]))");
var url = geturl.exec(string);
$('#urls').html(url[0]);
```

Trust me, putting url[1], url[2], etc. doesn't work :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Why only support `ftp|http|https|gopher|mailto|news|nntp|telnet|wais|file|prospero|aim|webcal`? `[\w\-]+` will match every protocol possible. For example, your regexp won't match `google-search:foobar`.

Comment: actually, i was only hoping to match urls with oembed support, but the pattern I found has all these protocols, maybe I'll just make it (http|https)...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass "g" in Regexp

```
geturl = new RegExp(
          "(^|[ \t\r\n])((ftp|http|https|gopher|mailto|news|nntp|telnet|wais|file|prospero|aim|webcal):(([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*(),;/?:@&~=-])|%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){2,}(#([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*(),;/?:@&~=%-]*))?([A-Za-z0-9$_+!*();/?:~-]))"
         ,"g"
       );


string.match(geturl).length
2

string.match(geturl)
 http://vimeo.com/8122132, http://www.flickr.com/photos/pmorgan/32606683/
```