# extract URI from given text (facebook like URL detection)

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to extract URL from a given text.
the URL can be in any format.with or wothout query string,with or without http:// ,https://,www. etc..

This is what i have so far

```
var mystrings = new Array;

        var text = $('#description').val();

        var re = /(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi;


        while (matches = re.exec(text)) {
            mystrings.push(matches[0]);
        }

        console.log(mystrings);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209016/javascript-extract-urls-from-string-inc-querystring-and-return-array

Comment: Tried this but it does not detect URLs like youtube.com/watch?v=ddfdfd or blog.example.com