# How can I found string from word using jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search

If I have one string that is,

```
currentUrl = "+http://localhost:30754/api/Index/PostStatus/+"
```

Split that string using "+" ,

```
currentUrl.split("+")
```

Output:

```
["", "http://localhost:60742/api/filemover/PostStatus/", ""]

0: ""
1: "http://localhost:60742/api/filemover/PostStatus/"
2: ""

length: 3
```

Now I want to find url that is "http://localhost:60742/api/filemover/PostStatus/"

Then how can I found using jQuery

**Note**:

I don't want to use this static way , want to get dynamically like on search word "http" , I can get path or full string

```
currentUrl.split("+")[1]
```

Thank you

Comment: what are you finding??

Comment: I want to find URL from array

Comment: @shivani in such cases you should use regular expressions

Comment: [This answer is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209016/javascript-extract-urls-from-string-inc-querystring-and-return-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the purpose of JQuery is to manipulate the DOM, this means it's doesn't come with a function to manipulate string in any way. The best way to get dynamycally some string within another string, is by using **Regular Expression**

Because you want to get the URL which is enclosed between **+** symbol using javascript you can perform that like this

```js
var chaine = "+http://localhost:30754/api/Index/PostStatus/+";

//  The pattern which I provide as parameter to the match method will capture everything between + symble

var regexResult = chaine.match(/\+(.*)\+/);
// the regexResult will be equal to the array provide bellow 
/*
Array [ 
    "+http://localhost:30754/api/Index/PostStatus/+",   
    "http://localhost:30754/api/Index/PostStatus/" 
]
*/

// because there are a match the URL will be accessible as the element at the index 1 of the array
var url = regexResult[1];

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using regular expression:

```
const r = new RegExp("^(\\+)(.*)(\\+)$");
const result = r.exec("+http://localhost:30754/api/Index/PostStatus/+");

// index 0 is the input
// index 1 the first group
// index 2 the rest of the string
// index 3 the the last "+"
const url = result[2];
```