# find value contain url or not in javascript/ node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I am trying to check if my output contain url or not
if it contain I want to do it like this  `{ "title": "Google", "href": "www.google.com" }`

so when I do `console.log(data)` the output data look like this

```
generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
https://www.google.com/
random@gmail.com,
10
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
![lost--rk](//images.random.net//3234r4/456545/4c653a1c200b5aa1/lost--rk.jpg)
4
default value
radio
```

so I am trying to check if my data contain url or not

and if it contain the url then it should make a json object which contain the title and href as key and in title the gitst initial value  which look like this

```
{ "title": "Google", "href": "www.google.com" }
{ "title": "Stackoverflow", "href": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" }
```

I tried this code I got from internet

```
if (new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(data)) {
console.log(data);
}
```

here I am also getting all this

```
https://www.google.com/
random@gmail.com,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
![lost--rk](//images.random.net//3234r4/456545/4c653a1c200b5aa1/lost--rk.jpg)
```

I only want url not other parts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

Comment: In fact I tried linking not the topic, but the second answer in it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943487/7916438

Comment: Alternatively, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18670370/7916438 shows a library you could consider checking.